# Building wall mountable PC

Tags: computer-building

I'm building a wall mountable PC with an ATX mobo and PSU. What I'm doing is using wood with carbon fiber on it and screwing the parts directly. However, I read somewhere that carbon fiber is a conductor so my question is: will my components be safe? If not, can I use rubber washers beneath every component to keep it from frying?

Secondly I don't have any motherboard standoffs on me either (and it's impossible to get them by themselves, where I live. Trust me ive tried :'( ), so can I just screw the motherboard directly on to the carbon fiber applied wood by drilling normal holes? Perhaps with rubber washers in between for further safety?

Comment: You should use standoffs anyway to allow for air circulation.

Comment: The rubber washers do leave space between the wood and mobo for air circulation

Comment: You can make spacers from something like the barrel of a ball-point pen.

Comment: Can you get longer screws instead of standoffs? Then add something to keep the distance; hollow wood blocks, whatever. And carbon fiber *is* a conducter, so add some isolation layer - whatever is available to you (e.g. plastic).

Comment: If the rubber washers are big enough, that would also do. Or use several.

Comment: I plan to use as much rubber washers as there are screw wholes i.e 10. I'd say they're big enough. 1.5cm radius for the rubber part(excluding the screw hole)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the things you've listed in your question, I see three potential issues with this approach:

- The metal case acs as EMI shielding for the system.  This both protects the system itself from interference from other electronics, and protects other electronics from interference from the system itself.  This is not anywhere near as critical as it used to be due to the general shift in favor of balanced differential signaling for busses, but it is still worth considering, especially if you're in an area with lots of EMI.
- The metal case is also important because it acts as a ground-plane.  Just like the shielding it provides, this isn't generally as critical as it used to be, but I can tell you from personal experience that even some modern hardware is less reliable if it's not well grounded.  Static in particular is much more of an issue without this grounding.
- The types of screws that are good for screwing into wood are not the same as the type that are good for mounting printed circuit boards.  This may not be a big issue, but at least make sure you don't try to use countersunk screws and hold the motherboard so that the mounting holes don't get torn up by the screws.

Now, all that out of the way, on to your primary questions:

Some carbon fibre products are conductive, some are not.  It's very hard to reliably determine this even with a multimeter, because you often can't get very good contact between the probes and whatever carbon fiber surface you want to test.  Given this, assume the carbon fiber is conductive, and make sure you have proper spacing between all the components.

As far as standoffs, you don't *need* them, but do make sure you still have the boards offset an appropriate amount from the mounting surface.  The normal standoffs you find in computer cases are between 12.5 and 18.75 mm long.  Make sure also that whatever you use to create this offset is rigid, not squishy (otherwise there's no point in having the offset, because if the supports sag, you'll end up in contact with the surface you're offset from anyway).  In your case, I'd look at hard-plastic washers if you can find them.  Teflon, nylon, or fiberglass should be sufficient (they're all reasonably good insulators).